# Running a loop based on input box answer

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro I want to run if the answer to the input box is `yes`.

So the question will need to be asked each time the other macro has been run I need to ask the question until the user has done the macro for all the dates they need to.

I am putting the input box in the wrong place but not sure where to put it.

```
Call ChangeDates

strMore = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Do you have any more dates to enter? Type Yes or No", Type:=2)

Do Until strMore = "no"

    If strMore = "yes" Then
        Call ChangeDates
    End If

    strMore = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Do you have any more dates to enter? Type Yes or No", Type:=2)
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this solution as an alternative to using an `InputBox`:

```
Sub test()  
Question:  
If MsgBox("Do you have any more dates to enter?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub  
Call ChangeDates  
GoTo Question  

End Sub
```

That way your users (or you) won't have to enter "Yes" or "No" in order to continue/end the process.

Comment: Thanks I used this one - as I didn't know you could do the question and thought that was a neat answer. @Arich

Comment: @louisathompson I'm glad it worked for you. :) Please mark my response as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim strMore

    Do Until strMore <> ""
        strMore = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Do you have any more dates to enter? Type Yes or No", Type:=2)

        '~~> Check if user pressed cancel or typed "NO"
        If strMore = False Or UCase(Trim(strMore)) = "NO" Then Exit Do

        '~~> Check if user entered "YES"
        If UCase(Trim(strMore)) = "YES" Then
            '~~> Rest of your code
            Call ChangeDates
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```